# Iterate through second values in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples

I have a list of tuples `[(0, 1), (0, 3), (4, 3)]` and I want a for loop that lets me work with the second value of each tuple. In this example I want the loop variable to have the values `1`, `3`, `3`. Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to use this:

```py
for tuple in list:
    ... = tuple[1]
```

To clarify, I'm looking for something like:

```py
for item in list:  # item is the second item in each tuple
    ...
```

Comment: Why do you have a problem with the first one?  That's the right way to do it.  Well, you wouldn't have `tupled[1] = ...`, because you can't change a tuple, but you could do `print(tuple[1])`.  BTW, it's a bad idea to name variables after built-in types, like both `list` and `tuple` are.

Comment: What I showed was just an example. And I would like to do it because my tuples are pairs of a score and an object, and since I need to work on the object it would make the most sense to have the variable in the for loop referring the object

Comment: `for score, obj in list:` / `print(obj)` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

for _, y in a:
    print(y)
```

If you want something more general and elegant, you can write your own generator function that yields the *n*-th element from each sequence in a specified iterable of sequences:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator, Sequence
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


def nth(n: int, it: Iterable[Sequence[T]]) -> Iterator[T]:
    for tup in it:
        yield tup[n]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
    for item in nth(1, a):
        print(item)
```

Both give the output:

```
2
4
```

**EDIT**: Added proper type annotations.